# Save to Text File from Infinite While Loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am currently writing data from an infinite while loop to an SD Card on a raspberry pi.

```
file = open("file.txt", "w")
while True:
    file.write( DATA )
```

It seems that sometimes file.txt doesn't always save if the program isn't closed through either a command or a keyboard interrupt. Is there a periodic way to save and make sure the data is being saved? I was considering using

```
open("file.txt", "a")
```

to append to file and periodically closing the txt file and opening it up again. Would there be a better way to safely store data while running through an infinite while loop?

Comment: Can you try and see if setting the buffering option to 0 makes any difference? It can be passed as a third parameter, `fileTest = open("file.txt", "a", 0)`. Please don't use the builtin name file to do stuff. Use another variable name.

Comment: file.flush() will maake sure the data is written. But you really should catch the exception and properly close your file.

Comment: It's not really an exception that stops the program. When I want to stop capturing data and move the data elsewhere I need to stop the program and that's where the data is not saving. I will try flush and see what happens.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A file's [`write()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) method doesn't necessarily write the data to disk. You have to call the [`flush()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.flush) method to ensure this happens...

```
file = open("file.txt", "w")
while True:
    file.write( DATA )
    file.flush()
```

Don't worry about the reference to `os.fsync()` - the OS will pretend the data has been written to disk even if it actually hasn't.

Comment: Damnit! I always underestimate python. I wrote a function that would periodically write to disk and now I find python does it automatically...

Answer (score 2):

Use a with statement -- it will make sure that the file automatically closes!

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as myFile:
    myFile.write(DATA)
```

Essentially, what the with statement will do in this case is this:

```
try:
    myFile = open("file.txt", "w") 
    do_stuff()

finally:
    myFile.close()
```

assuring you that the file will be closed, and that the information written to the file will be saved.

More information about the with statement can be found here: [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're exiting the program abnormally, then you should expect that sometimes the file won't be closed properly.

Opening and closing the file after each write won't do it, since there's still a chance that you'll interrupt the program while the file is open.

The equivalent of the `CTRL-C` method of exiting the program is low-level.  It's like, "Get out now, there's a fire, save yourself" and the program leaves itself hanging.

If you want a clean close to your file, then put the interrupt statement in your code.  That way you can handle the close gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

close the file and write the code again to the file.
and try choosing a+ mode