# Writing to CSV from an infinite while loop

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to write to a CSV file in a while loop, like this:

```
import csv

writer = csv.writer(open('rawi.csv', 'a'))

def rawi():
    # some other code

    writer.writerow(row)

def main():
    while True:
        rawi()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But this only writes when I interrupt the program with `Ctrl+C`.

I looked at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16864140/6282576), but `csv.writer` doesn't have a `flush` method.

How can I write to this file while the loop is running?

Comment: What is the motivation behind this?  Would a [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) framework be more suitable?

Comment: @0x5453 I want to run a script on my server to fetch random articles from Wikipedia and store their categories in a CSV file. The script needs to run forever, but I want to be able to access the file's content at any moment.

Comment: I suggest you close the file and reopen it. Since you're using "append" mode, it will keep adding additional row at end of the file.

Comment: cant you open the file and store it as a variable and pass that to csv writter then call flush on the file after you csv write?

Comment: @ChrisDoyle & @martineau, thanks. [Solved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58381847/6282576) it with `with`.

Comment: Amir: Actually I believe it's the `my_csv_file.flush()` in @Chris Doyle's answer that solves it.

Comment: @martineau Check out my answer, is there anything wrong with it? It seems to be working.

Comment: @Amir: Yes, your own answer looks like a valid solution, too — I was just correcting what you said in a earlier comment because it sounded like you might have a misconception about what was going on. However, using `flush()` would be a more efficient approach since it avoids having to reopen the file over and over (which is a relatively expensive operation).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

csv writer takes a file object. So instead of using open in the constructor call instead you could open a file first and then pass that file object to csv writer. The bennefit of this is that you now have access to the file object so can call its flush method. If you are using this method your best to open the file with newline set to blank.

```
import csv
import time
with open('query4.txt','a', newline='') as my_csv_file:
    csv_writter = csv.writer(my_csv_file)
    i = 0
    while True:
        csv_writter.writerow([i])
        my_csv_file.flush()
        i += 1
        time.sleep(1)
```

each time i open the file i see the new results.

**OUTPUT**

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
```

You can also acheive the same behaviour by openeing the file with `buffering=1` this will set line buffering and then you dont have to call the flush method of the file.

```
import csv
import time
csv_writter = csv.writer(open('query4.txt','a', buffering=1, newline=''))
i = 0
while True:
    csv_writter.writerow([i])
    i += 1
    time.sleep(1)
```

This has the same effect as calling flush after each writerow

Comment: @amir-a-shabani I added a second way to handle this without having to call the flush method on the file

Comment: Thanks, could you also check out my own answer? To see if there's anything wrong with it, because it seems to be working.

Comment: In object-oriented terms, you could say a `csv_writter` is an instance of `csv.writer` critter. `;¬)` Anyway, IMO setting the buffering to `1` would likely be the better approach because, besides avoiding the overhead of repeated calls to `flush()`, it's also making an assumption about undocumented internal implementation details regarding the file the `csv.writer` is using — which makes me slightly uncomfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [@Chris Doyle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381361/writing-to-csv-from-an-infinite-while-loop#comment103111535_58381361) and [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58381361/writing-to-csv-from-an-infinite-while-loop#comment103111396_58381361), I solved it like this:

```
import csv

def rawi():
    with open('rawi.csv', 'a') as rawi_file:
        writer = csv.writer(rawi_file)
        # the other code 
        writer.writerow(row)

def main():
    while True:
        rawi()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And we can see that it works:

[image: rawi.csv]